# Closure argument passed as @noescape to Objective-C has escaped

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch, synchronous, dispatch-queue

I'm trying to use a resource wrapper for a thread safe access. In my implementation, `awaitedValue` field performs a synchronous `read` of resource through a serial queue. For some reason, whenever I try to read this property, my app crashes with an error, which doesn't really make sense with synchronous code.

```
class ThreadsafeResource<T> {
    private let accessorsQueue: DispatchQueue
    private var resource: T
    
    //MARK: Initializers
    init(_ resource: T) {
        self.resource = resource
        self.accessorsQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "X")
    }

    //MARK: Synchronous access
    var awaitedValue: T {
        accessorsQueue.sync(flags: .inheritQoS) { // Point where my app crashes.
            self.resource
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried reading it from both `main` and `global(.utility)` queues – same result. And Asynchronous calls to resource work fine.

[image: Error screen and code example]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem manifests itself when you supply the `flags`. If you remove that, the problem goes away.

Looking at the stack trace, it’s failing in [`_syncHelper`](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-libdispatch/blob/77216601cc50d27d284ecf46d30229a570968853/src/swift/Queue.swift#L311), which declares the closure as escaping when it’s not really, AFAICT. This rendition of `_syncHelper` is called when you supply `flags` and it’s [not empty](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-libdispatch/blob/77216601cc50d27d284ecf46d30229a570968853/src/swift/Queue.swift#L363).

I'll file a bug report, as it would seem to be incorrect for `_syncHelper` to make that parameter as `@escaping`.

For now, I'd suggest you simply remove the `flags` parameter or consider a different synchronization mechanism.

Comment: I played around and found out that any flag, except `.barrier` causes this crash, so any QoS related flag, basically. As for a workaround: this does not happen to `DispatchWorkItem`s with flags, executed synchronously.

Comment: For those following along, the bug report for this appears to be https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-12479.